# Convert floating point byte array to decimal

Tags: c#, floating-point, bluetooth-lowenergy

I receive a 4-byte long array over BLE and I am interested in converting the *last two bytes* to a *floating point* decimal representation(`float`, `double`, etc) in C#. The original value has the following format:

```
 1 sign bit 
 4 integer bits 
11 fractional bits
```

My first attempt was using `BitConverter`, but I am confused by the procedure.

Example: I receive a `byte` array `values` where `values[2] = 143` and `values[3] = 231`. Those 2 bytes combined represent a value in the format specified above. I am not sure, but I think that it would be like this:

```
SIGN  INT FRACTION  
   0 0000 00000000000
```

Furthermore, since the value comes in two bytes, I tried to use `BitConverter.ToString` to get the hex representation and then concatenate the bytes. It is at this point where I am not sure how to continue.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Give examples... Too little info... How are the fractional bits expressed? In 12.345, is 345 the fractional bits? (and 12 the integer bits)

Comment: In case of "`values[2] = 143` and `values[3] = 231`" what is the answer? Is it  `-1.987793`?

Comment: Yes, for those values I get -1.987793 using your implementation

Comment: @John Szatmari: what is the right answer for "`values[2] = 143` and `values[3] = 231`", please? If you actually have, say, some weird BCD you may want some other implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question lacks information, however the format seems to be clear, e.g. for given two bytes as

```
  byte[] arr = new byte[] { 123, 45 };
```

we have

```
 01111011 00101101
 ^^  ^^    ..    ^
 ||  ||          |  
 ||  |11 fractional bits = 01100101101 (813)
 ||..|  
 |4 integer bits         =        1111 (15)
 | 
 1 sign bit              =           0 (positive)
```

let's get all the parts:

```
 bool isNegative =  (arr[0] & 0b10000000) != 0;
 int intPart     =  (arr[0] & 0b01111000) >> 3;
 int fracPart    = ((arr[0] & 0b00000111) << 8) | arr[1];
```

Now we should combine all these parts into a number; here is *ambiguity*: there are many possible different ways to compute fractional part. One of them is

```
 result = [sign] * (intPart + fracPart / 2**Number_Of_Frac_Bits)
```

In our case `{ 123, 45 }` we have

```
 sign     = 0 (positive)
 intPart  = 1111b = 15 
 fracPart = 01100101101b / (2**11) = 813 / 2048 = 0.39697265625

 result   = 15.39697265625
```

Implementation:

```
 // double result = (isNegative ? -1 : 1) * (intPart + fracPart / 2048.0);
 Single result = (isNegative ? -1 : 1) * (intPart + fracPart / 2048f);

 Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome:

```
 15.39697
```

**Edit:** In case you actually *don't have* sign bit, but use *2's complement* for the integer part (which is *unusual* - `double`, `float` use [sign bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format); 2's complement is for *integer* types like `Int32`, `Int16` etc.) I *expect* just an expectation, 2's complement is unusual in the context) something like

```
  int intPart  =  (arr[0]) >> 3;
  int fracPart = ((arr[0] & 0b00000111) << 8) | arr[1];

  if (intPart >= 16) 
    intPart = -((intPart ^ 0b11111) + 1);

  Single result = (intPart + fracPart / 2048f);
```

Another possibility that you in fact use *integer* value (`Int16`) with *fixed floating point*; in this case the conversion is easy:

1. We obtain `Int16` as usual
2. Then put *fixed floating point* by dividing `2048.0`:

Code:

```
  // -14.01221 for { 143, 231 }
  Single result = unchecked((Int16) ((arr[0] << 8) | arr[1])) / 2048f;
```

Or

```
  Single result = BitConverter.ToInt16(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian 
    ? arr.Reverse().ToArray() 
    : arr, 0) / 2048f;
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply! I just found out that the original value is supposed to be in 2's complement, and in this case, I suppose that multiplying by the sign wouldn't do it. Would converting the value to a 16-bit `Int`, taking the complement and adding 1 work?

Comment: @John Szatmari: no, to get *2's complement* in your case for the integer part is `int intPart =     (arr[0]) >> 3;` then `if (intPart >= 16) intPart = -((intPart ^ 0b11111) + 1);`.Please, notice that you want only **5** bits to be complement when **16**-bit `Int16` contains **16** bits

Comment: @Dimitry Bychenko: You were correct, I was actually using an **integer** ( `Int16` ) value with **fixed floating point**. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @John Szatmari: You are welcome! Next time, please, do not forget to *provide examples* for us not to *guess* (if you have a sign bit or 2's complement, or fixed floating point)